# Remote Client NotBoundException

Tags: java, client-server, rmi

I have just started and running the very first basic examples of RMI..
Dealing With many issues i finally ran ma project both from client and server side but when i ran client on a different m/c, i got the exception.

```
  Computeappengine exceptionCompute
    java.rmi.NotBoundException: Compute
at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.lookup(RegistryImpl.java:114)
at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Skel.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:390)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:248)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:159)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:155)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:535)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:790)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:649)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:255)
at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:233)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:359)
at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
at java.rmi.Naming.lookup(Naming.java:84)
at Client.computeappprog.main(computeappprog.java:21)
```

but when the client and server run on the same m/c , there is no issue.
i must mention that i tool help of vmware to have a server m/c
all firewalls turned off....

Comment: I think the client cannot look up the target server, and this would be about network configs :\, or you have just forgot run the server before client :?

Comment: when client can't lookup server , it gives connections refused error..

Comment: @user2511414 Definitely not. See the exception.

Answer (score 2):

> Remote Client unable to connect

No. Wrong title; wrong diagnosis. Read the exception. The remote client is unable to *lookup*. It's not the same thing.

That means that the remote object you looked up isn't bound by that name in the Registry you looked up. Either:

1. The bind()/rebind() call wasn't made, or
2. It failed, or
3. You looked up the wrong name, or
4. You looked up the wrong Registry.

Comment: seems you're good in rmi. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31970103/java-rmi-notbound-exception